# cake php Can someone explain $this->request->params['pass'][0];?

Tags: php, cakephp

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

I'm following this tutorial on the cakephp website. I'm stuck at this

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // All registered users can add posts
        if ($this->action === 'add') {
            return true;
        }

        if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
            $postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0]; //what is this?

            if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
```

What does this mean? I understand $this refers to the controller but what is param['pass'] where and how do they get this?

```
$postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the parameters that are passed in the Request String or Post Variables.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

> CakeRequest exposes several interfaces for accessing request
>   parameters. The first is as object properties, the second is array
>   indexes, and the third is through $this->request->params:

Comment: is there a way i can log what $this->request->params['pass'][0]; is passing through? with the cakephp debug kit?

Comment: @artSir yes, you should see it in the debugkit bar.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the best answer but all i had to do was return false

```
if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: well, it may have solved a problem you had, but it's definitely not an answer to your own question, you asked for an explanation on a variable and the previous answer supplied that, you should accept that one.